# export database table schema and move data to another machine using knex in node.js

Tags: node.js, database, knex.js

I have one running web service A with postgres, and I have also another running node.js service B which copies the postgres data from service A. Some people would suggest to use database migration, but here are two reasons I can't do it.

```
1. Zero Downtime for the web service A, so I can't do any migration on postgres on service A.
2. postgres database have tens of Gigabytes data, migration process might eat up my CPU or block the database, which I don't want to risk it.
```

I am thinking to use knex on service B(node.js) to fetch a postgres database on Service A, it is more like a simple ETL, the code below can work well as a example.

```
var knex1 = knex({
    client:'pg',
    connection:{
      database: co.database,
      host: co.host,
      user: co.user,
      password: co.password,
      port:co.port
    }
});
var sqlQuery = 'select * from abc';
var data = await knex1.select().from(knex1.raw('(' + sqlQuery + ') Wstmain'));
```

Although fetching data from postgres(service A) is fine, my problem is prior to inserting the data to postgres(service B), postgres database(service B) needs firstly know to the table schema and build up the table.

so right now I don't know how to use to get and export table schema on database A, then use the schema to create table on database B. I find a module called 'widget-knex-schema'.

```
const migrate =  require('widget-knex-schema');
const knex =  require('knex')({config...});

const usersSchema =  {
  id: {type: 'increments', nullable: false, primary: true},
  name: {type: 'string', maxlength: 200, nullable: false},
  email: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: false, unique: true},
  password: {type: 'string', maxlength: 254, nullable: false}
};

migrate.createTable(knex, 'users', usersSchema, true)
.then(function () {
  // success
})
```

It can create a new table with a json based schema, but how would I use knex to export such a json based schema from database A.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy database A to B `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are the easiest tools to do it https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html`

> pg_dump does not block other users accessing the database (readers or
>   writers).

So you should not to worry about DB getting blocked because of taking a dump.

Comment: it is not limited to postgres database, the reason I need to use knex is it can extend to mysql, postgres, oracle database.

Comment: The question did seem pretty specific about pg. Anyways for other databases there are other tools like mysqldump for mysql and expdp + impdp for oracle. Idea of writing your own code to extract and rebuild schema is a really bad idea and huge work and probably would end up with feature incomplete schemas + missing indexes to be copied etc. Either way you would need to write separate code for extracting schema from database metadata tables for each database engine.

Comment: Also it was unclear if schema A can change over time. If not then you could just hardcode db B schema generation to be the same with db A and then do the copy between two databases with knex (and make sure that you get consistent data to every table and fix relations etc.).